# Plotting animated pie chart using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, charts

I want to create an animated pie chart in JavaScript. I have done some R&D myself and found the Google Charts API.

But my major concern is the actual data is sent to the Google server for creating the charts. I am concerned about sending my data to a third party.

Answer (score 3):

If you're concerned about sharing data with a third party, you might consider an offline charting library, like [ZingChart](http://www.zingchart.com/). It gives you the ability to create animated pie charts quickly and easily without the need to transfer any of your data to a third party. This charting library works offline, and is dependency free. There are a number of animations that can be applied to the various types of charts, including pie charts. Check out this [animated pie chart demo](http://zingchart.com/playground/run/53fcf9c78c59b).

Lists of the different animation effects, methods, and sequences can be found on the [animation docs page](http://www.zingchart.com/docs/features/animation/).

I'm a member of the ZingChart team, so please feel free to ask if you have any questions! :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [jPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/)! You can do [Pie and Donut Charts](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/pie-donut-charts.php), [Bar Charts](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/bar-charts.php), [Line Charts](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/line-charts.php) and much more!. See the **[API](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/usage-txt.html)** here.

[**A DEMO here**](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/pie-donut-charts.php#chart1).

Answer (score 0):

[D3pie](https://github.com/benkeen/d3pie) is also a good option

They also have a [generator](http://d3pie.org/#generator) that you can use if you want to build your an example and work from there.